# Unit testing: what to do if the method/function to test doesn't exist

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, automated-tests

I have automated my tests by reading from a database the following information:

- the name of the method to be tested
- the input data for the method
- the expected result

For each row retrieved from the database, a test method is created using reflection.

Up to now, before creating the test method I check if the method to be tested exists. If it doesn't, the test method isn't created.

But I'd like to give information about the methods that still have to be written. From some point of view those are methods that don't pass their tests. So, what type of error or warning should be raised or issued in those tests?

---

P.S: I'm currently using `PyUnit` which is very similar to `JUnit`, but my question is not specific to any framework.

Comment: When you wrote "methods that still have to be tested" did you mean "methods that still have to be written"?

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What to do when a test fails depends on why it fails.

The safest default is to assume that a test has failed because the program has a bug. That's safest because it allows someone to write a test that fails when it should (which is after all the primary purpose of a testing framework) with the least knowledge and effort. So make your framework fail by default if a method isn't present.

But a test might fail because you've written the test but haven't implemented it yet. (Good for you, you're doing TDD!) If you write several tests before you implement any of them, you might want those tests to pass so you don't confuse work in progress with regressions. Indeed, some frameworks have a way of marking a test as work in progress, so that it doesn't fail but emits a warning to remind you to finish your work. That's how I'd handle your unimplemented methods.

In PyUnit, it looks like [the `skip()` decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures) is what you want:

```
@unittest.skip('method not implemented yet')
```